# Centering a Tikz Feynman diagram in the standalone document

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynmp, feynmp-auto

I would like to position the Feynman diagram at the center of the page and have it spread out. The code for the diagram is provided below. Could you please guide me on how to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\unitlength = 3mm

\begin{fmffile}{simple}
    \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
        \fmfleft{i1,i2}
        \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
   \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you incude 3 feynman related packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=10mm]{standalone}


\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\hspace{-10mm}
        \centering
\unitlength = 2.5mm
 \begin{fmffile}{simple}
    \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
        \fmfleft{i1,i2}
        \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
   \end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

output :
[image]